# Symfony v4, php bin/console doesn't work as expected. Automatically Aborted

Tags: php, symfony, console, command, bin

I just installed composer, php, apache etc. on my new SSD. After that I wanted to start coding. I opened my project from another drive in IDE. Then I wanted to load my fixtures into my new database, but I cannot. I cannot even make migrations etc. The php bin/console is broken (It automatically aborts any terminal input etc). I tried to run commands from other terminals, but it doesn't work. You can see commands below w/ or without -vvv. Thanks for any reply how to fix it.

**First:**

```
D:\project>php bin/console doctrine:fixtures:load
```

> Careful, database "project1" will be purged. Do you want to continue?
>   (yes/no) [no]:
>        >
>
> Aborted.
>
> doctrine:fixtures:load [--append] [--group GROUP] [--em EM] [--shard SHARD] [--purge-with-truncate] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [
>       -v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]

**One more:**

```
D:\project>php bin/console make:controller
```

> Choose a name for your controller class (e.g. VictoriousGnomeController):
>        >
>
> Aborted.
>
> make:controller [--no-template] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-in
>       teraction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]  []

**With verbose**

```
D:\project>php bin/console -vvv make:controller
```

> 2019-12-10T12:48:26+00:00 [debug] Notified event "console.command" to
>   listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\Deb
>       ugHandlersListener::configure".
>
> Choose a name for your controller class (e.g. AgreeableJellybeanController):
>
> > 2019-12-10T12:48:26+00:00 [error] Error thrown while running command "-vvv make:controller". Message: "Aborted."
> >         2019-12-10T12:48:26+00:00 [debug] Notified event "console.error" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Event\ConsoleErrorSub
> >         scriber::onConsoleError".
> >         2019-12-10T12:48:26+00:00 [debug] Notified event "console.error" to listener "Symfony\Component\Console\EventListener\ErrorLis
> >         tener::onConsoleError".
> >         2019-12-10T12:48:26+00:00 [debug] Command "-vvv make:controller" exited with code "1"
> >         2019-12-10T12:48:26+00:00 [debug] Notified event "console.terminate" to listener
> >     "Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Event\ConsoleErro
> >         rSubscriber::onConsoleTerminate".
> >         2019-12-10T12:48:26+00:00 [debug] Notified event "console.terminate" to listener
> >     "Symfony\Component\Console\EventListener\Erro
> >         rListener::onConsoleTerminate".
>
> In QuestionHelper.php line 137:
>
> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
>   Aborted.
>
> Exception trace:
>         at D:\apache\www\itnetwork\vendor\symfony\console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php:137
>        Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->doAsk() at D:\apache\www\itnetwork\vendor\symfony\console\Helper\QuestionHel
>       per.php:85
>        Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->Symfony\Component\Console\Helper{closure}()
>   at D:\apache\www\itnetwork\vend
>       or\symfony\console\Helper\QuestionHelper.php:437
>        Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->validateAttempts() at
>   D:\apache\www\itnetwork\vendor\symfony\console\Helper\
>       QuestionHelper.php:88
>        Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\QuestionHelper->ask() at D:\apache\www\itnetwork\vendor\symfony\console\Style\SymfonyStyle.p
>       hp:360
>        Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle->askQuestion() at D:\apache\www\itnetwork\vendor\symfony\console\Style\SymfonySt
>       yle.php:267
>        Symfony\Component\Console\Style\SymfonyStyle->ask() at D:\apache\www\itnetwork\vendor\symfony\maker-bundle\src\Command\MakerC
>       ommand.php:95
>        Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Command\MakerCommand->interact() at D:\apache\www\itnetwork\vendor\symfony\console\Command\Command
>       .php:240
>        Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at D:\apache\www\itnetwork\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php:1029
>        Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at D:\apache\www\itnetwork\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Console\Appl
>       ication.php:86
>        Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at
>   D:\apache\www\itnetwork\vendor\symfony\console\Applicat
>       ion.php:272
>        Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at D:\apache\www\itnetwork\vendor\symfony\framework-bundle\Console\Application
>       .php:74
>        Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application->doRun() at D:\apache\www\itnetwork\vendor\symfony\console\Application.php
>       :148
>        Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at D:\apache\www\itnetwork\bin\console:39
>
> make:controller [--no-template] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-in
>       teraction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]  []

Comment: Please add commands and error messages and such as text instead of image.

Comment: question updated

Comment: Thanks for formatting. I worked it out somehow. I've reinstalled php and composer multiple times and restarted PC.

Answer (score 5):

seems like this issue comes from a bug whitin the php 7.4 release on windows only

1. https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=78883
2. https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/4961

Other links:

- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34702
- https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/34754
- https://github.com/phpMussel/phpMussel/issues/211
- https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/4952