# symfony console make:controller aborted

Tags: php, symfony

I'm beginner in symfony v5 and i'm trying to make a controller.
I install all the dependencies and the symfony maker-bundle. When I write the command symfony console make:controller, it automatically aborted.
Here output:

C:\Users\Yazid Badarou\Documents\pinterest-project>php bin/console make:controller

Choose a name for your controller class (e.g. OrangePizzaController):
 >

Aborted.

make:controller [--no-template] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--]  []

Comment: Does it stop at the prompt for you to enter something or does it go straight to the Aborted and printing the help / CLI option output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upgrade your php version this issue is fixed 7.4.x

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at this topic: [Symfony v4, php bin/console doesn't work as expected. Automatically Aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59267313/symfony-v4-php-bin-console-doesnt-work-as-expected-automatically-aborted)

I saw you are on Windows and PHP is having a bug PHP 7.4.
I might use PHP 7.3 to fix it.